# How to adjust the volume of a sound in OpenAL?

Tags: iphone, openal

How can I adjust the volume of a sound in the OpenAL sound library?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982723/audio-processing-playing-with-volume-level

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
float newVolume = 0.4f;
alSourcef(currentSourceID, AL_GAIN, newVolume);
```

Comment: I believe he meant adjusting the device volume rather than the sound source gain. At least that's what **I** was hoping for when I found this question.

Comment: device volume?  Maybe you should look into the listener object?  Then you can easily set the listener's AL_GAIN with: alListenerf(currentSourceID, AL_GAIN, newVolume);

Comment: He said "of a sound".

Answer (score 3):

You can change the global volume by setting the gain of the listener.

```cpp
void Listener::setVolume(float v)
{
    alListenerf(AL_GAIN, v);
}

float Listener::getVolume()
{
    ALfloat v;
    alGetListenerf(AL_GAIN, &v);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your contribution, but it would be great if you could add some comments or notes about your code too! Will still upvote :)