# Getting raw sample data of m4a file to draw waveform

Tags: objective-c, signal-processing, audiotoolbox, m4a

I'm using AudioToolbox to access m4a audio files with following code:

```
UInt32 packetsToRead = 1; //Does it makes difference?

void *buffer = malloc(maxPacketSize * packetsToRead);

for (UInt64 packetIndex = 0; packetIndex < packetCount; packetIndex++)
{
   ioNumberOfPackets = packetsToRead;
   ioNumberOfBytes = maxPacketSize * ioNumberOfPackets;

   AudioFileReadPacketData(audioFile, NO, &ioNumbersOfBytes, NULL, packetIndex, &ioNumberOFPackets, buffer);
    for (UInt32 batchPacketIndex = 0; batchPacketIndex < ioNumberOfPackets; batchPacketIndex++)
    {
    //What to do here to get amplitude value? How to get sample value?
    }
    packetIndex+=ioNumberOfPackets;
}
```

My audio format is:
AppleM4A, 8000 Hz, 16 Bit, 4096 frames per packet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use extended audio file services. You just have to set up transition between client format and PCM. Got the right way overthere [Audio Processing: Playing with volume level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982723/audio-processing-playing-with-volume-level).

Answer (score 0):

To get waveform data, you may first need to convert your compressed audio file into raw PCM samples, such as found inside a WAV file, or other non-compressed audio format.  Try AVAssetReader, et.al.

Comment: AVAssetReader is way too slow for tge real time analisys. It was my first solution of this problem.